# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following lines of code to change the type of data in pandas DataFrame columns:

```
X["AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO"] = X["AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
X["WAKE"] = X["WAKE"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
X["PLANNED_TURNAROUND"] = X["PLANNED_TURNAROUND"].apply(lambda x: float(str(x)))
```

But I get an error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I can overcome this warming by doing `X1 = X.copy()`, but it may leak to a memory leak.

Comment: Do you create `X` as a slice from another `DataFrame` or from some other operation like `.drop_duplicates`?

Comment: "but it may leak to a memory leak." Why would it lead to a memory leak? Anyway, this is hugely inefficient to use `lambda`. Use `X["AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO"] = X["AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO"].astype(str)`

Comment: @ALollz: I create X as a slice from another DataFrame: `X = csvData[:-1]`

Comment: @roganjosh: Thanks. Answer: because it creates a copy of DataFrame. No?

Comment: Yes, so the warning is saying that your slice is a view on `csvData` and any changes will also be seen in the original data

Comment: That's different than a "memory leak" which is unrecoverable memory. You are correct that it will take up _more_ memory, but this is not a memory leak. Sometimes you really just have to make copies of data to avoid changes being propagated to other data that you hadn't anticipated; that is what the warning is warning you about.

Comment: @roganjosh: In my case it does not matter if the original DataFrame changes, because I do not use it anymore. I only want to remove warnings.